# Turning each string in an array into a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array with length 220 as follows:

```
var tF = ["PETMEI 2011: the 1st international workshop on pervasive eye tracking and mobile eye-based interaction","Pseudo-Volumetric 3D Display Solutions", .....]
```

I want to create an array like this:

```
var arr = ["PETMEI","2011:", "the", "1st", "international", "workshop".........]
```

I have tried this method but it doesn't work as intended:

```
var arr = Object.keys(tF).map(function(k) { return tF[k] });
```

Any ideas on how to create an array as fast as possible?

Here is my working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/whtb9ves/).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's an array of strings; split each one on spaces, and gather it up however you need it?

Comment: Just to point it out again: you don't have JSON and you don't have an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a string so just `.split` it

```
var arr = tF[0].split(/\s/);
```

If you want all of `tF` flattened into one big array,

```
var arr = [];
tF.forEach(function (e) {arr = arr.concat(e.split(/\s/));});
```

Comment: Also `tF[0].split(/\s/).filter(Boolean);` will remove the extra empty array items that are blank (caused by double spaces)

Comment: @wahwahwah It'd be better to do it as `.split(/\s+/)` instead of two steps. I didn't write this as OP didn't define behaviour for such occurrences though

Answer (score 2):

You could use `map` followed by `concat`:

```
var arr = tF.map(function(k) { 
    return k.split(' ') 
});
arr = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arr);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/whtb9ves/2/

Comment: `Object.keys(tF).map` for an array? just `tF.map` would be better.

Comment: If you wanted the index, it's the second param of the map fn, no need to `.keys` in this particular case

Comment: @xdazz: Thanks, I wasn't looking carefully enough at the original code. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

This is the shortest one.

```
var arr = tF.join(' ').split(/\s+/);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this:

```
var arr = tF.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b.split(/\s+/));
}, []);

console.log(arr);
```

**[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/whtb9ves/3/)**

Comment: Reduce works so often but I so rarely think to use it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use array concat?

```js
var tF = ["PETMEI 2011: the 1st international workshop on pervasive eye tracking and mobile eye-based interaction","Pseudo-Volumetric 3D Display Solutions"]

var newArr = [];

for(var key in tF)
{
  newArr = newArr.concat(tF[key].split(' '));
}

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand it correctly, what you need to do is "split" the string by " " to turn it into an array of words.

http://jsfiddle.net/whtb9ves/1/

```
var arr = Object.keys(tF).map(function(k) { return tF[k].split(" ") });
```

If you are looking at splitting by words - you might want to look at normalizing it too, such as removing punctuation etc. It does depend on the application...